# Field shadowing or overriding?

Tags: java, overriding, shadowing

I have two classes (A and B) and B extends A.

```
public class A {
   protected int i = 1;
}

public class B extends A{
   protected int i = 2;
}
```

In this case the program writes 1.

```
A a = new B();
System.out.println(a.i); //1
```

But if I assign value i in the constructor it writes 2.

```
public class B extends A{
   public B(){
      i=2;
   }
}

A a = new B();
System.out.println(a.i); //2
```

Why?

Comment: This is called _hiding_.

Comment: Which is hiding, which is overriding?

Comment: Your first example, `B.i` is hiding `A.i`. There is no overriding fields, only hiding them.

Comment: Fields cannot be overridden. Only non-static and non-private methods can be overridden.

Comment: But if B.i is hiding A.i, why not writes 2 because of the dynamic binding?

Comment: There is no dynamic binding with fields. They are resolved based on the static type of the reference.

Comment: So in the second case isn't there hiding?

Comment: No, you just inherit the field normally and set its value.

Comment: But if in the second case there isn't dynamic binding, why does the program write B.i?

Comment: There is no `B.i` in your second case, only the `A.i`.

Comment: So in both case the program writes A.i, but in the second case I changed A.i to 2?

Answer (score 2):

From [the official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html):

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super, which is covered in the next section. Generally speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult to read.

Fields aren't polymorphic, and you keep a reference on a `A` object. By executing `i = 2`, you change the value of the field, hence the result modified.

Related question: [Hiding Fields in Java Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244670/hiding-fields-in-java-inheritance)