# Non overridden method doesn't show subclass field

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Parent {
    String st = "external";

    void print() {
        System.out.println(st); 
        System.out.println(this.st);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String st = "inner";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Child().print(); // shows "external"
}
```

Why does `print()` called on subclass not show the string "inner"?

Comment: You're [hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) your superclass variable with the one in your subclass, not overriding it.

Comment: in my opinion a good question +1

Comment: actually i found similar problem here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244670/hiding-fields-in-java-inheritance)

Comment: @VivyenAndzuana yes, that is exactly the same problem. I would prefer you question nevertheless (although it is a duplicate) because it is really minimal and thus easier to understand. would be really great if you keep it that way in the future. SO is full of oversized questions... where mostly one line is in question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why print() called on subclass doesn't show string - "inner" ?

Because member variables cannot be overridden. The member variable `st` in class `Child` does not override the member variable `st` in class `Parent`. The two member variables are two separate variables, which happen to have the same name.

The methods in class `Parent` see the member variable `st` that is defined in class `Parent`, and not the one in class `Child`, even if the object is really an instance of class `Child`.

Only methods can be overridden.

More information in Oracle's Java Tutorials: [Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) (thanks @JonK).

Comment: Here's the official documentation of this feature if you want to include a link to it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

Comment: Thanks, so how to access child field from print method without overriding the method?

Comment: That would only be possible by casting to `Child`: `System.out.println(((Child) this).st);` but that would be bad design in a real Java application. A superclass should not depend on a specific subclass in that way.

Comment: To dig deeper on this, why can't you override the method?  In this trivial example, it's definitely the right call.  Is there some real-world constraint that prevents this?

Comment: Sure i can, but now i gonna work on understanding of hiding because i didn't know that i could stumble on this =)

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned the field `st` of the `Parent` class is hidden. Just an addition if you want it to print "inner".

Change `Child` class to this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public Child() {
        st = "inner";
    }
}
```

This way the value of `st` from the `Parent` class is overriden!

Comment: Just note that this only works if `Parent` and `Child` are in the same package - if they're in different packages you would need to declare `st` to be `protected` in `Parent`.

Comment: @JonK this is true. but this is not the case as the example suggests.

Comment: Yes - it's just something that the OP needs to be aware of

Comment: @JonK at this stage it will only confuse OP... so.. in my opinion too much information. there is a lot to inheritance which OP will learn, but here only this special question mattered.

Answer (score 0):

> why print() called on subclass doesn't show string - "inner" ?

why should it? you are calling the method `print()` that is only override in the parent class up there in the parent class st is only holding the value "**external**"

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover why the behavior you notice is expected, so I won't touch on that.  In terms of a solution to your problem, there are a few worth mention (neglecting things like reflection and subclass casting; technically solutions, but poor ones).

#### Option 1: Set Parameter

As Will mentioned, can simply set the parameter in Child:

```
class Child extends Parent{
    public Child() {
        st = "inner";
    }
}
```

#### Option 2: Method Override

Can also override the `print()` method (because, as mentioned, only methods can be overridden).  `Child` would become something along the lines of:

```
class Child extends Parent{
    ...

    @Override
    void print() {
        // Child-specific implementation here.
    }
}
```

This will result in `Child` objects using their print method in place of `Parent`'s method.

#### Option 3: Strategy Pattern

Another option is to use Strategy pattern. Consider the following:

```
public interface Strategy {
    String getString();
}

public class ParentStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "external";
    }
}

public class ChildStrategy implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "inner";
    }   
}
```

From here, all you need to do is change your Parent object so that it defaults to ParentStrategy, provide accessors to change the Strategy, change its print method to use the getString() method of its Strategy object, and change the Strategy in Child to use ChildStrategy:

```
class Parent{
    Strategy strat = new ParentStrategy();

    void setStrategy(Strategy s) {
        strat = s;
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println(strat.getString()); 
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    public Child() {
        super();
        setStrategy(new ChildStrategy());
    }
}
```

In real world applications, this pattern is a fundamental tool to making flexible applications.