# Beginner Question about java superclasses and subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, instance, instance-variables

I have a question about instance variables in java classes.

I have the following class Employer.java

```
public class Employee {
    String name = "";
    public double salary = 0;

    public double getEarnings() {
        System.out.println("Super Earnings: " + salary);
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Here is my Manager class as a subclass of Employer:

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
    public double bonus;
    public double salary = 0;

    @Override
    public double getEarnings() {
        return super.getEarnings() + bonus;
    }
}
```

In the main function I try to set the bonus and  I have the following code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Manager myMan01 = new Manager();
        myMan01.name = "Mike";
        myMan01.salary = 3000;
        myMan01.bonus = 2000;
        System.out.println(myMan01.getEarnings());
        System.out.println(myMan01.salary);
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be 5000. But it actually is 2000.

I know I have instantiated the salary variable in the superclass and the subclass, which seems to be causing the output. I just don't understand, why `myMan01.salary` is not called by `super.getEarnings()`. Can anyone please clarify?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the formatting. Lots to learn, still :)

Comment: Please add the code, how you instantiate the `myMan01` instance. And where did you specify the `super.getEarnings()` call in your code?

Comment: What is ```result``` variable in ```Manager#getEarnings()```? Did you mean ```salary``` instead?

Comment: I edited that part. The code is a little different. By changing it to making it concise, I made a mistake.

Comment: The problem you have here is called _shadowing_. You have two _entirely_ separate fields both named `salary`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244670/hiding-fields-in-java-inheritance ?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark the question as answered, I will recite some comments.

The answer to this problem seems to be polymorphism (although as a beginner I have to wait to later chapters in my textbook to fully understand).

- The problem you have here is called shadowing. You have two entirely separate fields both named salary. – chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- 1 hour ago
- Possible duplicate of [Hiding Fields in Java Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244670/hiding-fields-in-java-inheritance)

As stated by the comments of chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- and Joe.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getEarnings()` method in your Manager class I think you have a typo, you return `result + bonus` instead of `salary + bonus` !

And you don't need the `salary` variable, it is inherited from the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable called `result` in your code. I think you made a typo there.

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
    public double bonus;
    public double salary = 0;

    @Override
    public double getEarnings() {
        return this.salary + this.bonus;
    }
}
```

It is always good to make instance variables `private` access modifier and use **getter** & **setter** methods for each variable to associate with them. (Encapsulation in OOP)

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. The output is still not what I expected.